# Closing Embedded Demo Player After Completion

Tags: javascript, embedded, javascript-framework

Let me begin by saying I am NOT a developer. I work in digital banking and mainly focus on SEO and Marketing. I have embedded this demo into our live site for training and I would like it to close automatically when the demo is completed. Here is the script.

```
function Function29(){  
$('#player').empty();
 Lemonade.DemoPlayer.play({
        demo: '750e8759-6fa1-45be-aa8a-03f02cbe45af',
        container: $('#player'),
        locale: 'en_US',
        finishButtonText: 'Continue',
        horizontalPadding: 25,
        onFinish: function() {
$("#player").html(
              "Click anywhere to continue"
            );
            // you can do anything when the game ends!
        },
        onStepChange: function (previousStep, currentStep, currentHotspot, totalSteps) {
            // every time the scene changes, this event is called
        },
    });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If by closing, you mean, hiding or removing the player container, which I'm assuming is `#player`,

you can simply call `$('#player').remove();`

Question: Did the `$('#player').html('Click anywhere to continue');` do anything for you? If so, you can run `$('#player').remove()` from `onFinish: function() {...}` you have.

Can you add your HTML script to show more details? Thanks! I'll edit my response depending on that.

Comment: function Function15(){    
$('#player').empty();
 Lemonade.DemoPlayer.play({
        demo: 'c4bfeb4d-0ec0-49fd-b742-f8ceaf318503',
        container: $('#player'),
        locale: 'en_US',
        finishButtonText: 'Continue',
        horizontalPadding: 25,
       $('#player').remove()
            // you can do anything when the game ends!
        },
        onStepChange: function (previousStep, currentStep, currentHotspot, totalSteps) {
            // every time the scene changes, this event is called
        },
    });
}

Comment: function Function15(){    
$('#player').empty();
 Lemonade.DemoPlayer.play({
        demo: 'c4bfeb4d-0ec0-49fd-b742-f8ceaf318503',
        container: $('#player'),
        locale: 'en_US',
        finishButtonText: 'Continue',
        horizontalPadding: 25,
       $('#player').remove()
            // you can do anything when the game ends!
        },
        onStepChange: function (previousStep, currentStep, currentHotspot, totalSteps) {
            // every time the scene changes, this event is called
        },
    });
}

Comment: I don't have access to the HTML. We use a CM called sitecore and it doesn't give much access to the code.

Comment: Can we define what    finishButtonText: executes? Like when the continue button is clicked, remove the player?

Comment: @LeeWedel finishButtonText feels like the `text` that should be displayed on the button. Usually, you would find something like. 

onFinishButtonClicked
finishButtonAction
finishButtonOnClicked
onClick

And then you can supply an action. Something like

```
onClick = function() {
  alert('Do this.');
}
```

If you can at least do something that invokes the alert function, you might as well be able to remove the player.